# Why would the emitted signal from repeating binary data over a wire appear at a frequency lower than the bit frequency?

Tags: sampling, frequency, signal-detection

I have a signal over which binary data is transferred over wire in a repeating 10 bit format. The wires that the data is send over are CML, DC coupled 3.3V twisted pairs, and the protocol of encoding has DC balancing. A possible example would be that it send 1000110101 (actual data over wire) at 2MHz. The signal that the wire emits would have a frequency of the bits frequency (20MHz).

However, when I analyze the electromagnetic signal emitted using a spectrum analyzer it appears the base frequency of the emitted signal is the 10 bit format frequency (2MHz).

Using the assumption that more transitions makes the electromagnetic emission of the signal stronger, sampling at the 10 bit frequency (2MHz) with an SDR and plotting it by `round(sample / (max_sample / 10))` gives the correct amount of transitions per sample.

My guess would be that the repeated format of the signal is the cause?

Comment: "Using the assumption that more transitions makes the signal stronger," What does *stronger* mean? Not energy-wise, at least!

Comment: The definition of frequency is "when something repeats, how often does it do that per unit time?".

You just literally said how often it repeats.

So, what exactly causes the confusion? I might simply be not understanding the question!

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit? When you say the 10 bit sequence is sent at 2 MHz, I assume that's the carrier? Also, how are the bits encoded?

Answer (score 1):

If you send the same pattern again and again, you have a periodic signal which has a line spectrum and the fundamental frequency is the inverse of the time period.

If you send a random bit pattern at the same rate the spectrum will depend a lot on how the individual bits are encoded

Answer (score 0):

The highest possible fundamental frequency to be emitted is when we send the binary pattern 10101010…. Note that we send each bit at the data rate but the repetition of the pattern will be half the data rate. For higher order modulations where we can send multiple bits for each symbol transmitted, the emitted frequency (relative to the carrier) will be even less.